# loop through two objects in the same template

Tags: twig

I'd like to be able to loop through two objects side-by-side in a template, like this:-

**Application.php**

```
return $twig->render('index.twig', ['fixtures' => $fixtures, 'weathers' => $weathers]);
```

`fixtures` & `weathers` are both arrays containing objects.

**templates/index.twig**

```
{% extends "frame.twig" %}
{% block content %}
    {% for fixture in fixtures and weather in weathers %}
        {%  include 'fixture.twig' with [{fixture: fixture}, {weather: weather}] %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

There should be 4 rows with `fixture` and `weather` data *together*. I get 8 rows - 4 with `fixtures` and 4 with `weather`. So, looping twice which is not what I want?

Edit

The goal is something along the lines of:

```
<div class="border py-2 bg-light  mb-3 fixture">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center text-center teams">
        <div class="col-5 themed-grid-col text-right font-weight-bold text-uppercase">{{ fixture.homeTeam() }}</div>
        <div class="col-2 themed-grid-col">{{ fixture.kickoff() }}</div>
        <div class="col-5 themed-grid-col text-left font-weight-bold text-uppercase">{{ fixture.awayTeam() }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center font-weight-light location">{{ fixture.location().name() }}</div>
    <div class="text-center font-weight-light location">{{ weather.getTemperature() }}</div>
</div>
```

My data is awkward with arrays of objects where I'm unable to do a simple `array_merge`

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  object(\Fixture)#16 (5) {
    ["id":"\Fixture":private]=>
    int(413456)
    ["awayTeam":"\Fixture":private]=>
    string(15) "Birmingham City"
    ["homeTeam":"\Fixture":private]=>
    string(9) "Brentford"
    ["kickoff":"\Fixture":private]=>
    string(5) "15:00"
    ["location":"\Fixture":private]=>
    object(\Location)#17 (3) {
      ["name":"\Location":private]=>
      string(12) "Griffin Park"
      ["latitude":"\Location":private]=>
      float(51.4872912)
      ["longitude":"\Location":private]=>
      float(-0.3036014)
    }
  }
 
}
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  object(\Weather)#22 (8) {
    ["client":protected]=>
    object(\WeatherApiClient)#23 (6) {
      ["client":protected]=>
      object(GuzzleHttp\Client)#24 (1) {
        ["config":"GuzzleHttp\Client":private]=>
        array(8) {
```

Comment: I would suggest combining fixtures and weathers in the backend so you can iterate over one object. Hard to say why you get 8 instead of 4 without knowing the content of the objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming from your question, `fixtures` and `weathers` are corresponding items meaning the `weather` linked to the `fixture` should/would have the same index (or key if the array is associative).

If this is this the case, then you can change your loop to the following:

```
{% for key, fixture in fixtures %}
    {%  include 'fixture.twig' with { fixture: fixture, weather: weathers[key]|default } %}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/29lkd0)

Comment: added an edit to show a snapshot of my data backend

Comment: As pointed out in my answer, if the keys matches then this snippet will work for you. There is no need for merging any arrays